# Class Verification?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, verifyerror

I have seen a lot of verifying error in android apps at runtime. Also, I have seen suggestions regarding adding -dontpreverify option in proguard.

**I have two question**

1. Are preverify in proguard and runtime class verification in android related?
2. Is there a good way to debug or fix verification error in the obfuscated code?